# One table - two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have hierarchical structure for model `Board` (implemented using ancestry gem).

Instead of one model and some scopes, I'd like to have two models: `Board` for root level elements (`ancestry` column value is `nil`), and `Category` for the rest(`ancestry` column value is `not nil`). They would be using the same table `boards`.

How can I do something like this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can explicity define a table for a model using `set_table_name` or `self.table_name` depending on your rails version. Also you can define a default scope for every query made for this model, using `default_scope`, so a combination of both should be what you are searching for:

```
class Category < AR:Base
  self.table_name = 'boards'
  default_scope where('boards.ancestry IS NOT NULL')
end
```

Answer (score 6):

You could specify the table name of the category model and generate a default scope:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "boards"
  default_scope where('boards.ancestry IS NOT NULL')
end
```

And you should be able to interact with both models wit the boards-Table.

Or you stay with one model and add two modules for the specific stuff. That depends on your preferences.

Comment: Wow, exactly the same answer, hahaha, that was funny.

Comment: and both posted at exactly the same time. There should be a Gold badge for that!