# Rails 5.2 - how to setup a relationship between a parent and a typed child model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a basic model structure like this:

```
Template - has_many :cards
Card - belongs_to :template, optional: true
```

When a `Card` is created, the user selects a `Template` and upon saving it, the `template_type` is set to 'list'.

A `Card` can only have one 'list'.

How can I create a relationship that will give me a method on the `Template` model that will allow, given an instance of a card, that I can do this:

```
my_card.list
```

and from a given template instance (that is of `template_type` 'list'):

```
this_template.card
```

I think the current problem is that the column in the template model is called `template_type` when perhaps it should have been just called `type`. It is implemented as an enum:

```
enum template_type: { template: 0, list: 1 }
```

But also I need to define the typed relationship on the models.

**What I have tried**

Card.rb

```
  belongs_to :list, class_name: 'Template', optional: true, inverse_of: :owner
```

Template.rb

```
  belongs_to :owner, -> { where.template_type[:list] }, inverse_of: :lists
```

Although that allows me to do

```
my_card.list
```

it is null (even though m`y_card.template` returns a template with `template_type` of 'checklist').

I am guessing that would need a migration to add `owner_id` to the template table. But this does not seem correct as the card table already as a field called 'template_id', so all I need is for Rails to use that to access the template (of type 'list') that belongs to it, through a method called checklist. And to do the reverse from a template (of type 'checklist') to find its 'owning' card.

As a second question, how can I enforce a rule that a card can only have one Template of type 'list'?

**EDIT**

I also read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18315889/one-table-two-models) and wonder if I should setup a separate model called `List` that encapsulates the domain better?

**UPDATE in response to comment**

A list is structurally identical to a template except it can be 'completed' whereas a template cannot. The user can create as many lists as they like from a single template, and each list is linked to a card which keeps track of what they do with the list.

There was no point creating a separate table for a list, since it is basically identical to a template other than that (it has a completed or not completed status flag, which is a filed in the template table, but a template_type of type template will never use it).

Comment: Adding a `type` column causes Rails to treat your model as if it's implementing STI. Using `template_type` would be correct for your application. In regard to your second question, just create a custom validation that checks whether or not you have a list and if you have too many, generate a validation error. Here is a reference:  https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods Can you elaborate more on what `list` does in your question?

Comment: @CannonMoyer Ok thanks for confirming (1) re type/template_type. The validation I can understand, but I am leaning more towards creating a separate model for list, as per the idea in the question I linked to in my edit.

Comment: Looks like you need Self-Referential Association

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my 1st question, I had to tell Rails to use the existing foreign key:

card.rb

```
belongs_to :list, class_name: 'Template', foreign_key: 'template_id'
```

template.rb

```
has_one :card, inverse_of: :list
```

Now I can reference a card from a list and a list from a card. No database changes needed. :)

Thanks to @CannonMoyer I managed to add a custom validation for my 2nd question:

```
  validate :template_is_a_list

  def template_is_a_list
    errors.add(:template, 'must be of type list') unless
       template.template_type == Template.template_types[:list]
  end
```